plotly plots not being displayed when data given through javascript in flask application
I am having a html code with dropdown and a plotly plot (comes from python's flask route). I need to update the plot based on the values selected in a dropdown (trying for single selection now).
I am trying to update the plot using below javascript function. But I am getting blank display when i am changing value in dropdown. Thanks in advance
document.getElementById('plotselected').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var plotSelect = document.getElementById('plotselected');
    var selectedPlot = plotSelect.options[plotSelect.selectedIndex].value;

    // Create a FormData object and append the selected commodity
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('plotselected', selectedPlot);

    // Make a fetch request to the Flask endpoint
    fetch('/getS3Plot', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        
        console.log(response)
        var existingExperimentSelect = document.getElementById('plot-container');
        existingExperimentSelect.innerHTML = `{{ ${data}|safe }}`; 
        // Plotly.react('plot-container', data); 
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
});

Note: I am already having {{ fig|safe }} in the plot_container (div element in html)
Below is the Flask route that updates the plot
@app.route('/getS3Plot', methods=['POST'])
def getScreen3Plot():
    filenames = os.listdir('uploaded_files')
    csv_filename = [filename for filename in filenames if filename.endswith('.csv')][0]
    df1 = pd.read_csv(f'uploaded_files/Aluminium_dataset_csv_tj.csv')
    plot = request.form['plotselected']
    list = {"PDF":plotPDFSC3(df1).to_html(''),"CDF": plotCDFSC3(df1).to_html(''),"BoxPlot": plotBoxSC3(df1).to_html(''),
            "LineChart": plotLineSC3(df1).to_html(''),"Scatter": plotScatterSC3(df1).to_html(''), "Histogram": plotHistogramSC3(df1).to_html('')}
    
    # return list[plot]
    return Response(list[plot], mimetype='text/plain')

